# Simulator bug After update visual Studio and iOS version

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, ios11

I am working on Xamarin.iOS with Visual Studio in Mac. After Updating my Visual Studio When I run my Application It display horizontal line in my Selction see the screen for better understandment.

Normal Screen :

[image]

When Selection is Open Screen :

[image]

**Bug Screenshot :** 
[image]

And this is bug When Selection is done it display horizontal line. This is working fine in iOS 10 till. But in iOS 11 it display the line.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use "UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone" property as "tableView.separatorStyle".

Comment: @Tann This is not `TableView` it is `PickerView`.

Comment: It will be a little bit tricky.
use this : ((UIView *)[self.pv.subviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Ironman How do you hide this PickerView(probably InputView)?